# What are various sites to publish erotica?

Tags: publishing, erotica

Where could I look, or what could I search for, in order to find sites that allow user based publishing of erotic stories online?

The only site I currently know of is literotica.com. I am not trying to advertise for them, this is the one example I know of, it is no more an ad than if I listed agentquery.com or manuscriptwishlist.com when looking for how to find an agent.

I am not encouraging anybody to go read erotica. I am interested in whether other writers know of additional places to publish erotic stories, or have found a way to search for them. I think this question is general and could help other authors that may hesitate to ask.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! Could you [edit] your question to add something about what criteria you are looking for in the sites and whether or not you are affiliated with the site? Right now this looks an aweful lot like spam... If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: I don't understand why this is being closed; we allow questions on finding agents and publishers, which I have found helpful. We allow questions about finding beta readers and reading groups. Is this simple prejudice against writing ***erotica***?

Comment: @Amadeus I agree. I also find no evidence for thinking that this is spam either. It seems to be a legitimate question looking for simple information. The question is very brief and no further clarification has been given—but I'm not really sure if more clarification *does* need to be given.

Comment: Personally I reported the question, because it is very broad. What research has he done? Has he tried to look on other sites? Did he looked on other questions regarding publishing on this site? I'm lacking some informations, like @Secespitus mentioned in his comment. At the moment, this all looks to me like just commercial

Comment: @Amadeus In fairness, this question seems more similar to "which publisher should I use?" (which is likely opinion-based) or even "which publishers are available?" (which is broad, likely even if restricted by genre) than "how do I find a publisher?" (which can be a legitimate question). To be honest, personally I'm torn on this one. The one thing I don't think this question is, honestly, is *unclear* -- it seems perfectly clear enough to me what OP is asking. Whether it's a *good, on-topic* question for us is a different matter.

Comment: @Varun To put the comments above in perspective, you may want to review [What topics can I ask about here?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [How to not be a spammer](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/promotion), both in our [Help].

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I see two recent Q "How do you generally share your novels with the masses?" and "Where to find a place to publish a specific kind of work?", also "Where can I find literary agents that publish books by minors?". Search "is:question find an agent" (15 res) & "is:question find a publisher" (50 results), mostly unmolested by "Close" votes, often with a handful of answers. This seems like a lot of close votes for THIS Q, whether an argument can be made for being on topic or not, we generally allow these questions to proceed. IMO all that is different here is the word "erotica".

Comment: **I have nominated this question for re-opening;** because (as my comment above shows) IMO it is little different than many other questions that received no close votes at all; thus I suspect and believe the "close" votes are motivated by objections to writing "erotica", which is not a valid reason to close a question. Writing erotica is a valid pursuit, both in entertainment and commercially, and in the USA at least covered by freedom of speech. I do not believe this question is off-topic, any more than a hundred other questions about where one might publish their work, for pay or otherwise.

Comment: @Pawana Not having done any other research is not a reason to close a question. Most questioners here have not done any other research; this IS their research; asking other experienced authors. This is no worse than somebody asking "how do I find a publisher for my genre? All I know about is xyz.com."

Comment: Voted to re-open

Answer (score 4):

One quite effective alternative is:
[storiesonline](http://storiesonline.net)

They have the option to also post non-erotica, and have a very effective categorisation tool.  You can actually find writing on a reasonable breadth of topics here,  although the primary focus is erotica.

Another place to post original work online is:
[fictionpress](https://www.fictionpress.com/)

They don't appear to have an erotica category - so I suspect hardcore material would not be allowed - but some perhaps soft-core stuff would be welcomed in the romance section.

If you go to the effort of setting up your own site for publishing then this is a great place to promote that work:
[topwebfiction](http://topwebfiction.com/)

Comment: Another site they might consider is questionablequesting.com. There's also a number of fanfiction sites that allow erotic content, though often they're restricted to fan works of a single fandom. Of course, none of this would help them find a publisher for their works - often, publishing your content online first will prevent a publisher from being willing to publish book versions of your works.

Answer (score 1):

I think Wattpad allows erotica in their stories and is a pretty popular platform from what I can tell, check them out and see if that works out for you. You could also just publishing collections or novella's through kindle and build a following through twitter. I have found a number of decent erotica authors go this route. It certainly saturates the environment more, but erotica/romance fiction has always been a high demand market so if you build those connections through social media you could definitely find some decent readership.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is not considered spamming, but I thought some of you might be interested in the site I run: [noveltrove.com](https://noveltrove.com). It's an erotic stories website, it's ads-free (free in general) and we are always happy to welcome new authors, including newcomers who are not sure "if I'm good enough" (you probably are). Feel free to visit and decide for yourself.

If you are looking for more sites, simply search for "erotic stories" on your favorite search engine, and you shall find what you are looking for. If you are looking for a specific niche, just add it to the search term. There are various smaller sites and forums catering to all kinds of fetishes.

Just one thing for your journey, don't share any personal information, if you are not totally comfortable with it, but you know that already. Stay safe and have fun!

Edit: I don't have enough reputation points on stackexchange to add a comment, thus I'll just add to my original post. We are a judgement-free zone and members are welcoming. Currently we got ~2500 user accounts. The site is financed by me, and I'm not selling or sharing user data.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! As long as the affiliation is easily seen and the reference answers the question it's okay. But it would be nice if you could explain what differentiates your site from others. Currently it looks like you have a site and the biggest advantage is that it's ad-free. How does it work? How many people are there? Do you have any big content-related "selling points"? And I am always a bit more careful when I read "ad-free" - how do you make money? If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: The page [How to not be a spammer](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) in our help center might be interesting for you to read. It talks about things to do and not to do when mentioning your own services/products/...

Answer (score 1):

I also run a small erotica site for amateur writers. Anyone can access our library and read user submitted stories. If anyone wants to post stories, they just simply sign up. Our users have access to a personalized dashboard, forums, writers desk, faqs, and more. This is all free. Eventually we will add affiliate marketing, but as of now (July 2021) our site is ad free. We will be adding more user features soon, we invite anyone to stop by to read or write erotica. [www.PBXstories.com](http://www.PBXstories.com)

Answer (score 0):

The Alt Sex Stories Text Repository at https://www.asstr.org/ started as  a collection of stories posted to the usenet group alt.sex.stories, but broadened to host text erotica from anywhere. It, includes both web and FTP access. Some authors have set up mini-web-sites within ASSTR.

Note, the home page includes a NSFW image.